# Basic Excel 'IF Formula' Where entering by entering a value in one cell, will take the value of one of several other cells in same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

OK - so based on what I have been trying to find here - this is a laughable question to most on this site...but here it is...

I would like to write maybe an  `IF` formula wherein, if I enter into `A1` one of 7 letters it will enter into `B1` the value contained in either C1,D1,E1, and so on..

For instance -

If in A1 someone types 'a' then the value of C1 goes into B1

If in A1 someone types 'b' then the value of D1 goes into B1

If in A1 someone types 'c' then the value of E1 goes into B1

Sorry for the simple explanation but really have had a hard time finding the answer on other searches / community help etc.  I thought it was basic but still above my skills so I thought I would try spell it out very plainly...it seems this solutions would be as easy as blinking your eyes (or adding 2 + 2) to most of the posters on this site regarding Excel forumulas.

I just want at the point of data entry someone to type in a letter so that a value updates from one of several cells who's formulas and vaues are pre-written but for the life of me can't seem to find this seemingly simple equation through multiple searches...Thanks in advance for any help on this and sorry to ask such a basic question.
[image: Concept Image - Entering a value/letter in Column 'B' draws from one of several columns depending on letter entered]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your setup, you can simply use `HLOOKUP` but let me know if I didn't understand your question correctly.

Here is the screenshot of how I do it based on your sample:

[image]

The formula you fill out from `cell D2` should be:

```
=HLOOKUP(B2,$F$1:$L$9,ROW(),0)
```

Please let me know if this is not what you want and we can work on other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about an IF statement.  You could use a *nested* IF statement where if the first condition is not met, you put the next IF statement in the FALSE section of the first and repeat until you have entered all your options.

```
=IF(A1="a",TRUE (C1),FALSE (next if statement))
```

The other answers are correct in that if you have more than 3 or 4 nested IF statements then you should really start looking for another cleaner solution.

```
=IF(A1="a",C1,IF(A1="b",D1,IF(A1="c",E1,"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
=OFFSET(B1,,CODE(A1)-96)
```

[image: SO46146085 example]